# open a link in chrome, verify URL link and switch back to my app. How can i do this?

Tags: android, selenium, appium

Click on mobile video player ad it takes to Chrome browser ad URL then I need to get back to mobile app. But need to confirm that ad opens in browser. So it is like switching from app to chrome and chrome to app. platform is Android.

Please Any help. I am completely new in automation and learning by myself.